# Generating random Graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

Have someone input an integer N as the number of vertices in the graph.

- Assign random weights on each edges ranging from 1 to 10. Not all possible edges
  are present though! As in the above example, represented an absent edge by an X.
- Return a pair (M,L), with M and L respectively being the matrix and list representation
  of the (same) random graph you are generating.
- Use non-digit characters as vertex names, to avoid confusion with edge weights.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void gen_random_graph(int n)
{
    int adj_matrix[n][n];
    for(int u = 0; u < n; u++)
    {
        for (int v = 0; v < n; v++)
        {
            if(adj_matrix[u][v]==adj_matrix[v][u])
            {
                adj_matrix[u][v] = rand() % 10 + 1;
                cout << adj_matrix[u][v] << endl;
            }
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int N;
    cout << "enter number of vertices" << endl;
    cin >> N;
    gen_random_graph(N);

    return 0;
}
```

THis is my code so far. Is it generateing the weights ? and what does it mean i have to return a pair?

Comment: Firstly, your `vertex` is an input to this function, so you shouldn't be also replacing that value with the value from the command line using `cin`. You should be updating `vertex` from the command line outside this function and passing in whatever you found from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

A graph can be represented as an N x N adjacency matrix (as you have already set up), where the value in `matrix[i][j]` corresponds to the weight of the edge connecting vertex `i` to vertex `j`. A zero corresponds to there not being a connection between `i` and `j`. If `matrix[i][j] == matrix[j][i]`, then you have an undirected graph. Furthermore, a random graph would have random values as the edges between vertices.

In the case where every edge either exists or doesn't exist (i.e. weights are either 0 or 1), you could have the following:

[image: Undirected graphs]

This image is stolen from the internet, so I take no credit for it. Note that you can easily confirm that the first graph is undirected because the adjacency matrix is symmetric. Likewise, the second graph is directed because the matrix is NOT symmetric.

Comment: okay some when i made the N x N that already generated a graph correct? and how would i set the weight? in the for loop i would do adj_matrix[u][v] = rand() % 10 + 1?

Comment: it basically has to be undirected random weight graph

Comment: @Darkflame I will not write it for you because you certainly have enough information now to create it yourself. You're close, but as-is your code will be accessing uninitialized data when `u<v`. Try iterating only through one half of the matrix and setting two values each time. Good luck.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not asking you to write it for me i am confused  as to how to get the edges if it is randomly generated by a graph N x N =/   and since u said that matrix[i][j] is the weight of the edge from what i can understand is that i just created a N x N matrix but i don't see how it is connected randomly